# How to "follow" people with the new Twitter API in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, ios5

Is it possible "follow" people on Twitter using the new Twitter API in iOS 5?

If so, how? I can't seem to figure out which way to go here.

Can someone post an example using `TWRequest` please? Thanks.

Comment: I asked for an example because I'm stuck. That's what this place is for. Your comment helps me in no way, so why post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [the existing Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

Here is a blogpost describing all the details ( article 2 in a series of 2 ):
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-2.html

Answer (score 6):

Add Twitter and Accounts frameworks, and use the following method:

```
- (IBAction)tweet_action
{        
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempDict setValue:@"numerologistiOS" forKey:@"screen_name"];
                [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];

                TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json"]
                                                             parameters:tempDict
                                                          requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];


                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"%@", output);
                    if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        UIAlertView *statusOK = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                 initWithTitle:@"Thank you for Following!"
                                                 message:@"You are now following us on Twitter!"
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [statusOK show];
                        });
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: It has worked for me. Thanks. Keep posting such useful information. Coding rocks man.