# Twitter Follow API

Tags: twitter

I need to get the person is following another person in twitter using the API.

I know the twitter migrated to v1.1

I used these API to get the relationship between two person,

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a=Person1&screen_name_b=Person2

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/lookup.json?screen_name=Person1,Person2

But i get the final result is,

```
{
errors =     (
            {
        code = 215;
        message = "Bad Authentication data";
    }
);
}
```

Is there any other exact API to find the my solution.

Any one help me to find the one person is following the another one.

Comment: The error is "Bad authentication data" - have you correctly registered you app and got your authentication tokens?

Comment: Terence Eden Thanks for ur reply. i used this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085055/how-to-follow-people-with-the-new-twitter-api-in-ios-5 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you can get what you are expecting,

```
-(void) followUsOnTwitter {

ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [tempDict setValue:@"abcd" forKey:@"screen_name"];    // Change the Value String
            [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];

            TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"]
                                                         parameters:tempDict
                                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                NSLog(@"%@", output);
                if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200)
                {

                    // follow by usr

                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with this answer :
In the v1.1 API, they have replaced it with the friendships/lookup API where you can specify a comma separated list of up to 100 users and it'll tell you about the connections between the authenticating user and each of the users specified

Comment: Anil Dhiman, I checked it with this also, Just see my question in that 2nd link,..